# PostgreSQL exploit not loading in MSFConsole from ExploitDB

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, kali-linux

Just trying to get a postgreSQL exploit (32847.txt - Low Cost Function ) from exploitdb to run in msfconsole. After pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it isn't loading, here I am. I'm using Kali Linux, Debian 64 bit in Virtual Box, Windows Host.

So far here's what I've done:

Downloaded appropriate exploit from exploitdb, placed .txt into a folder that I made, `.../.msf4/modules/exploits/PostgreSQL`. I run `ls` in command line, I can see it there.

Rerun terminal, updated db via `-updatedb`

Started msfconsole, and it did not load the exploit into msfdb (I can't access it via `use exploit ....`. I've tried to update the db and tried to both copy/paste the exploit directly via GUI into the exploits folder as well as through command line.

My error is `Failed to load module: exploit/PostgreSQL/32847.txt`

Am I placing the exploit in the wrong folder or what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems with what you are trying to do to use this [exploit](https://www.exploit-db.com/raw/32847).

First, while Metasploit is an exploitation framework that any exploit could be ported to, it requires modules to conform to a few specifications. As far as I know, all modules must be written in Ruby, and need to contain configuration parameters and standard functions so that the framework can operate on it. The "exploit" linked above was certainly not designed for Metasploit, which brings us to the second problem.

If you look at that "exploit" file, not only is it not a valid Metasploit module, but it is not even a script or code at all (hence the .txt extension). The file's purpose is to tell you how to test the vulnerability manually and is not meant to be run in any way.

So, if you really want to use that exploit with Metasploit, you would need to write your own module for it.

Comment: Haha cool - appreciate it. Learning as I go!